# How to fix Golang nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 6 [9: Bad file descriptor]

Tags: macos, go, networking, process, fork

Hello I have a simple Go app running on macOS Mojave 10.14.4 with `go version go1.15 darwin/amd64`

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "os/exec"
)

func main()  {
    _, _ = http.Get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
    exec.Command("ls").Start()
}
```

It runs without any errors but if you run it while having the Console app you will see the following error logged from `/usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib`:

```
nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 6 [9: Bad file descriptor]
```

The error gets triggered by the line `exec.Command("ls").Start()`, you can use a breakpoint or put it inside a loop to see it occur every time that line executes. Anyone knows what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Note: it does not happen with all URLs, for example `https://www.facebook.com` does not trigger the error.

Update: An additional detail, the error also doesn't show if I compile that app with go1.11.13

Comment: What kind of "fix" are you looking for? There's nothing technically wrong with your code, this looks like either a problem with Mojave itself (newer versions don't seem to do this) or the Go runtime. Completing the http request and/or waiting on the subprocess like you would in a normal program may help.

Comment: I used `.Start()` in my example to show that is enough to reproduce. Waiting for it to complete still triggers the console error. I was wondering if anyone understood why it happened in the hopes of finding a workaround. For example, making the http request to  `https://www.facebook.com` instead of `https://stackoverflow.com/` does not trigger the error, perhaps there is some configuration that can be used in the http request that could help.

Comment: An additional detail, the error also doesn't show if I compile that app with go1.11.13.